WCF service not generating JavaScript reference file on client side app after updating service reference
I encountered an issue with my client app where i am using a wcf service. Assuming when service reference is updated,client app will have a js file which looks like (https://test/portal/ajaxwebService.svc/js).This js file expected to have API names using AjaxWebService references. This is working fine. similarly i have another wcf, when service reference is taken for this in client app, it supposed to have a js reference file which should look like (https://test/portal/GridService.svc/js) but this does not exist. I received a 404 (Not Found) error in the browser console.
I attached screenshot below.
 https://i.sstatic.net/dKaXQ.png
https://i.sstatic.net/dxmpX.png
Here's what I've checked so far:
Both services are WCF projects in .NET.
Verified service configurations to ensure that they match.
The web.config files for both services are similar.
I'm unable to identify the root cause of this problem. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue effectively

Is it possible to transfer a new js file to the client via WCF code?
